# Linker Error C++ "undefined reference "

Tags: c++, reference, undefined

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Trying to compile my program via `g++ -o prog1 main.cpp -std=c++0x`

I get the error:

```
/tmp/cc1pZ8OM.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x148): undefined reference to `Hash::insert(int, char)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <functional>
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
//preset prime number 
int prime = 101;
hash<char> h1;
int key;
Hash HashTable;

// check for Request & string parameters
if(argc != 3) {
    cout << "Run program with 2 parameters. [Lower Case]" << endl;
    cout << "[1] insert, find, or delete" << endl;
    cout << "[2] string" << endl;
}

if(strcmp(argv[1], "insert") == 0) {
    //Get Hash for argv[2] aka value
    key = h1(*argv[2]);

    //check 1
    cout << "Hash: " << key << endl;

    key = key % prime;

    //check 2
    cout << "Mod 101 Hash: " << key << endl;

    HashTable.insert(key, *argv[2]); //PROBLEM here

}

return 0;
}
```

**Hash.h file:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

class Hash {
//100 slot array for hash function
LinkedList *hashFN[100];

public:
void insert(int key, char value);
//void deleteItem(int key);
//char* find(int key);


};
```

Any ideas? Using this to build a hash table with set size.

Edit: **Hash.cpp** file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Hash.h"

using namespace std;

void Hash::insert(int key, char value){
*hashFN[key]->addFront(value);
cout << "Success!" << endl;

}
```

Trying to compile via terminal now with:

> g++ -c Hash.cpp -o Hash.o
>
> g++ -o prog1 main.cpp Hash.o -std=c++0x

It goes into an infinite loop somehow.

Comment: Where is Hash.cpp file? Where is definition of Hash::insert function?

Comment: Thinking the problem is you're inserting a char * not a char. Having the same error but as far as I can tell everything looks good function-wise. Onward the search goes....

Answer (score 59):

Your header file `Hash.h` declares "what `class hash` should look like", but not its implementation, which is (presumably) in some other source file we'll call `Hash.cpp`. By including the header in your main file, the compiler is informed of the description of `class Hash` when compiling the file, but not how `class Hash` actually works. When the linker tries to create the entire program, it then complains that the implementation (`toHash::insert(int, char)`) cannot be found.

The solution is to link all the files together when creating the actual program binary. When using the g++ frontend, you can do this by specifying all the source files together on the command line. For example:

```
g++ -o main Hash.cpp main.cpp
```

will create the main program called "main".

Comment: What if I want to compile two files separately and then link them together? The linker cannot find functions within the second file however they have been declared in the main file. It seems that the makefile Fox has wriiten in orange box is OK but when I use it, it says 'undefined reference to ....'

Answer (score 30):

This error tells you everything:

> undefined reference toHash::insert(int, char)

You're not linking with the implementations of functions defined in `Hash.h`. Don't you have a `Hash.cpp` to also compile and link?

Answer (score 0):

Your error shows you are not compiling file with the definition of the `insert` function. Update your command to include the file which contains the definition of that function and it should work.